# What's the correct way of sharing functionality between activities?

Tags: java, android, methods

Suppose I'm building an Android app, and I have two separate activities. Both do similar things, but maybe the layout is diferent. Let's say I have a button in each activity, and both buttons do the same thing, but I don't want to be redundant about it.
Could I just define a public method in one of the activities and then call that method from the other one too?
Even further, could I create some java class PublicMethods and just put in it all the methods that I want to share between activities?
I haven't seen this anywhere else, I think, so I suppose there is a good reason not to do this, but I can't figure out what it is.
Is this bad practice? If so, why? And if this is the case, what would be a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not very specific about what you are trying to achieve I'm guessing mayb you could just create an object and then call it from the activities and pass parameters determined on what you are trying to make it do, and even just send what you want through the activies by using intent putExtra and just used the Extra in your activity.